# Prevent GridLayout to Strech Ouside The Screen

Tags: android, text, grid

I have a `GridLayout` with a `ColumnWeight` set to expand the middle column. this column has text on it, so the purpose of the `weight` is to make it expand as much as it wants to fit the text.

But if the text is too big, I would like it to add ellipses to the text and preserve the last column on the edge of the screen.

The behavior I am getting is that the last column is pushed out of the screen and the middle column grows as much as it wants....**How can I prevent this?**

Here's a sample code on how to replicate this issue:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    app:columnCount="3"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    app:rowCount="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="- Start Text -"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test "
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"            
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="- End Text -"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_gravity="right"/>        

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

A curious thing to note is that if I add an `android:maxEms="5"` to the middle `TextView`, it works as expected, **does anyone knows why?** I don't want to add something like an `android:maxEms="5"` because this will limit the length of the text, instead I want it to occupy all available space left on the screen (and if I use `android:maxEms="5"` the `5` will have to be choosen for a specific minimum screen size).

Comment: can u drop some sample code

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade I made a quick one for testing since my original one is pretty big to post here.

Comment: you can try to use columnSpec attribute to define the column space.

Comment: Yeah, but again, this isn't going to stretch, it's going to be limited to a minimum screen